# Index was out of bounds of array? c# forms

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to read the following textfile:(skipping first 8 lines) And reading from arrow each column
[image]

And am doing so by putting each column value in an array which is dictated by position and length

To test if the array value actually captured a column value I want to see the value[0] when I click another button. But when I run my app, I get the error that my index was out of bounds of the array? How, when my array size is 3 and I don't go beyond that.

```
    string[] val = new string[3 ]; // One of the 3 arrays - this stores column values

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName).Skip(8).ToArray();
            textBox1.Lines = lines;

             int[] pos = new int[3] { 3, 6,18}; //setlen&pos to read specific clmn vals
             int[] len = new int[3] {2, 10,28}; // only doing 3 columns right now



             foreach (string line in textBox1.Lines)
             {
                 for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
                 {
                     val[j] = line.Substring(pos[j], len[j]); // THIS IS WHERE PROBLEM OCCURS
                 }

             }

        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   // Now this is where I am testing to see what actual value is stored in my    //value array by simply making it show up when I click the button.

        MessageBox.Show(val[0]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arrays are `0` indexed,  that means that an array with 3 elements will have elements at indexes `0`, `1`, and `2`.

`3` is out of bounds, so when you try to access `pos[3]` or `len[3]`, your program will thrown an exception.

use `j < 3` instead of `j<=3`

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
 {
     val[j] = line.Substring(pos[j], len[j]); // THIS IS WHERE PROBLEM OCCURS
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you go all the way up to `j == 3` in the `for`statement. This will be the fourth element since arrays are zero-based, so change the `for` statement to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
```

and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

The array `pos` has three values in it.

Consider your for loop.

1. First i is zero.  That is less than or equal to three.
2. Then i is one.  That is less than or equal to three.
3. Then i is two.  That is less than or equal to three.
4. Then i is three.  That is less than or equal to three.
5. Then i is four.  That is *not* less than or equal to three.

It executes the body of the loop 4 times.  There are 3 items.

For the fix, to follow standard conventions, just use a less then, rather than a less than or equal to, in the condition check of your `for` loop.